# Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

[SQL Server 2008 R2 warning when tried to execute the script of size approx 500MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdObC.png)

When I tried executing a SQL script which was of 500 mb approx. Management Studio throws an error

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

My system memory is 8GB and only 3GB is free. I tried SQLCMD but it's not working. Any other solution for this?

I faced this issue when I was trying to restore a database using backup of higher version (SQL Server 2014) to a lower version (SQL Server 2008 R2) using scripting method.

Comment: Check the drive where temp db is pointing  there is space issue..

Comment: yeah..i have checked the location of TempDB and i didn't find any space issue there..i have 100 GB approx

Comment: Sounds like you have a zillion insert statements in a script. Perhaps you should try BCPing each table out to native files instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can run big scripts using command line.

Ie :

sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -U sqlusername -P sqlpassword -i C:\myScript.sql

[link details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms170572.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.105).aspx

the maximum batch size is 256 MB (65.536 * 4 kB).

You will have to split the script into several smaller ones.

Comment: Thank you..Can you please tell me the possible ways to split the script apart from BCP OUT and BULK INSERT to insert data.

Comment: I'd probably create a separate script for each table's data.

Comment: thank you...Probably i'll try that.and if you have any other solution for this can you please share it?